# How to realise a generic compare ? ( for numbers as well as strings)

Tags: c++, templates

Looking for the best method to realize a Class-Method which uses a generic compare.

I have a array of either nubers or a array of strings and then look for either a specific number or a specific string(which is given to my funcion) in that array.

The problem is: If I have strings I need a stringcompare, but stringcompare doesnt work when I have integers or doubles.

Would use template, but im kinda new to that topic.

```
template <class data_Type> class Foo //data_Type can be int, double or string
{
public:
    Foo(data_Type field_x[])
    {this.field_x = field_x;}

    int get_index(data_Type xy_variable)
    {
        u = sizeof(field_x) / sizeof(field_x[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
        {
            if (xy_variable == field_x[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    data_Type field_x[];
}
```

Comment: Side Note: `data_Type field_x[];` is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: `std::string` supports comparison by `operator==`, can you elaborate what do you mean by saying *but stringcompare doesnt work when I have integers or doubles*?

Comment: You can ask for a comparator via template arguments, similar as to what `std::set` does for example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a templated class, but need an exception for a specific type, as you do for strings, you can use specialization.

add this outside your class, in the header

```cpp
template<>
int Foo<std::string>::get_index(std::string xy_variable);
```

And then you can write a separate implementation that uses your favorite string comparison.

```cpp
template<>
int Foo<std::string>::get_index(std::string xy_variable) { /*...*/ }
```